# PyroCMS 3 problematic install. Problem starts with This form is not secure. Autofill has been turned off

Tags: php, laravel, http, get

This is a duplicate question, 100%. ...I have tried a great many solutions from other answers, which haven't worked. I searched for the errors with site:github.com, which may indicate it is a Laravel issue and not necessarily a PyroCMS 3 issue. I have searched here-- I found plenty of people that have asked the same question, but their answers just don't fix my problem.

My initial login after the install goes a lot like this:

"This form is not secure. Autofill has been turned off." Click!
"Send Anyway" Click!
Whoops! "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." The sadness. No joy.

I am just not sure what to do.

Looking at other posts, I have cleared the cache with optimize:clear and the route cache. I am on about my tenth successful install-- sort of. I tried with PHP 8, which didn't work. I am trying with PHP 7.4 now. Just not sure quite what to do. I have specified my raw domain when prompted, I have specified domain.com:443 when prompted. ...I have to have gotten the passwords to match what I entered at least once.

Here is a youtube video:
https://youtu.be/LKxmxv6t07A

Edit: I know where the problem is!

My URLs are being generated as http://domain.tld/whatever, the code is autogenerating insecure URLs.

Here is the forgot password link as an example:

```
<a href="http://www.dibbsonit.com/users/password/forgot?redirect=%2F">
```

Answer (score 0):

My Nginx site config:

```
# --------------------------
#
# Redirect non-www > www
#
# --------------------------

#server {
#    listen      80;
#    listen      443 ssl;
#    server_name www.example.com;
#    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
#}

# --------------------------
#
# Redirect to HTTP > HTTPS
#
# --------------------------

server {

# I generally like it the other way around, raw redirecting to the www subdomain.
# Regardless, that is something I will play with more later.
#    if ($host = www.example.com) {
#        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#    } # managed by Certbot


#    if ($host = example.com) {
#        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#    } # managed by Certbot


    listen      80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return      301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
# While I am spraying Whoops! messages...
# Just let people with my public IP address in.
# There is a similar whitelist feature in the pyrocms admin settings.
#    allow 123.45.67.89;
#    deny all;

# Listening on port 80 allows application level redirecting to SSL pages
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    index  index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/pyrocms/public;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;

    # Remove trailing slashes
# This had to go. This was the main source of my boot loops.    
#    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

#    expires $expires;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
# There are three places I know to change the "FORCE_SSL" setting:
#     In the admin GUI (difficult to change if things go sideways)(the GUI updates the DB value).
#     In the database under the table default_settings_settings directly.
#     And as an environment variable here, subjectively the easiest place for me to manipulate it, if I needed to.
        fastcgi_param  FORCE_SSL true;
#        fastcgi_param  APP_URL https://example.com;
#        fastcgi_param  APPLICATION_URL https://example.com;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {

        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;

        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.ico$ {

        expires 1w;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the config file to specify that HTTPS should be forced. It is quick and easy if you have access to the file.

If you do it in the UI and something breaks in a way that prevents the application loading, you can go into the database and change the configuration value there. --But, that takes longer, for me anyways.